# (^@) null character appear in python loggging file

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to write a python script(support several parameter delivered in), want to use python logging to record all the user activities with this script.That means, several users may run script simultaneously.
At begin of script `main()`, define logging related stuff.

However, in logfile, I found there are lots of (`^@`) null character.
What's wrong with the script? Could anyone give root cause of this? thanks!

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
```

```
In main():
    . . .

    # If log_file not exist, create and chmod
    if not os.path.exists(log_file):
        with open(log_file, 'a+'): pass
        os.chmod(log_file, 0666)

    # Config logging format
    log_formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt='[%(asctime)s]  [%(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d]  [%(levelname)s]   %(message)s',
                                    datefmt='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')

    f_logging = logging.getLogger('')
    f_logging.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # maxBytes limit to 10MB, backupCount to 2 to backup max 2 log files. NO encoding, NO delay.
    f_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_file, mode='a', maxBytes=10*1024*1024, backupCount=2, encoding=None, delay=0)
    f_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)

    f_logging.addHandler(f_handler)

    cmd_line = ''
    for arg in sys.argv:
        cmd_line += arg + " "

    f_logging.info("[user:%s]   %s" % (cur_user, cmd_line))

    f_handler.close()
    f_logging.removeHandler(f_handler)
    . . .
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem end with multi-process issue, multi-process logging into same file from different machine.